# Resolving Error: Running Xilinx through Wine

Tags: software-installation, osx, wine, .desktop, ndiswrappers

I've run the [Xilinx 14.7 Full Installer for Windows](http://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/design-tools.html) successfully via Wine on the prefix `com.xilinx.verilog`, then went to `~/Library/Application\ Support/com.xilinx.verilog_145331572525077/` to confirm that all the installed files are in-place, which they are under `c\:/14.7/ISE_DS` along with `ISE Design Suite 14.7.desktop` located under `c\:/users/patrick/Destop/` and `ISE Design Suite 14.7.lnk` located under `c\:/users/Public/Desktop/`. The contents of the `.desktop` file, generated by installing Xilinx, are:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=ISE Design Suite 14.7
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/Users/patrick/Library/Application Support/com.xilinx.verilog_145331572525077" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /Users/patrick/Library/Application\\ Support/com.xilinx.verilog_145331572525077/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/ISE\\ Design\\ Suite\\ 14.7.lnk
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Comment=ISE Design Suite 14.7
Path=/Users/patrick/Library/Application Support/com.xilinx.verilog_145331572525077/dosdevices/c:/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE
Icon=E55D_ise.0
```

And I tried running the `Exec` string directly in the Terminal, but I get the error:

```
err:module:import_dll Library NDIS.SYS (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\npf.sys") not found
err:winedevice:ServiceMain driver L"NPF" failed to load
err:winediag:SECUR32_initNTLMSP ntlm_auth was not found or is outdated. Make sure that ntlm_auth >= 3.0.25 is in your path. Usually, you can find it in the winbind package of your distribution.
fixme:iphlpapi:NotifyAddrChange (Handle 0x10ef550, overlapped 0x10ef55c): stub
wine: configuration in '/Users/patrick/Library/Application Support/com.xilinx.verilog_145331572525077' has been updated.
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specified file.
ShellExecuteEx failed: Success.
```

How can I resolve this error?

**EDIT** I found out that `npf.sys` was missing due to failed installation of WinPcap, so I downloaded that separately from the site and now running the `Exec` string gives me this error:

```
err:module:import_dll Library NDIS.SYS (which is needed by L"C:\\windows\\system32\\drivers\\npf.sys") not found
err:winedevice:ServiceMain driver L"NPF" failed to load
DbgPrint says: XPC4DRVR.SYS: DriverEntry - V1.04...
DbgPrint says: XPC4DRVR: Create Device name (\Device\XILLPT-1)
DbgPrint says: XPC4DRVR: Create Device link (\DosDevices\XILLPT-1)
DbgPrint says: XPC4DRVR: Port name (LPT1) for deviceObject (001113A8h)
fixme:ntoskrnl:IoInitializeTimer stub: 0x1113a8, 0x54315d, 0x111460
DbgPrint says: XPC4DRVR:  Failed initializing timer! Status: C0000002
fixme:exec:SHELL_execute flags ignored: 0x00000100
Application could not be started, or no application associated with the specified file.
ShellExecuteEx failed: Success.
```

I checked and `npf.sys` is indeed located in `c\:/windows/system32/drivers`. Now what?

Comment: I'm currently attempting to install under a fresh prefix with the Win7 winetrick. I'll see how that goes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to try and start the `.lnk` file directly by opening the DOS Prompt from the wine menu with the `com.xilinx.verilog` prefix set. After navigating to `C:\users\Public\Desktop` I ran `start "ISE Design Suite 14.7.lnk"` and it opened the application window! I'm currently looking for a nicer way to run it, but I'm excited to have it working without needing to run Bootcamp!

**EDIT**

I ended up creating a shortcut application using the AppleScript editor, and pasted the following code in:

```
set winePref to "/Users/patrick/Library/Application Support/com.xilinx.verilog_145332206926253"
set execPath to winePref & "/drive_c/users/Public/Desktop/ISE Design Suite 14.7.lnk"
do shell script "env WINEPREFIX=" & quoted form of winePref & " /opt/local/bin/wine start /Unix " & quoted form of execPath
```

Note that your particular binary path for `wine` could be different than mine, so make sure you check that.